# P2V Server 2008R2 with vmware converter 4.3.0 No source volumes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, physical-to-virtual, vmware-converter

I'm trying to P2V a Windows Server 2008R2 to vmware vsphere 4.1 using Vmware vCenter Converter standalone 4.3.
Source Box

```
Windows Server 2008R2
24GB ram
Dual Quad-Cores
1 Raid 5 drive 680 GB
  3 GB "Recovery" partition
  40 GB OS partition
  637 GB Data partion
```

When we try and convert using the stand alone converter and the built in vCenter converter there are no source volumes listed. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out how to do it... On server 2008R2 if you install Vmware vCenter Converter standalone 4.3 on the machine you want to convert and then run the converter as admin it will show you your drives and you'll be able to P2V it.

Comment: Also you can do it remotely but log in as a local administrator.

Comment: So, how do you do this on a Domain Controller???

Comment: This solution aslo applys to a P2V of a Windows 7 Pro computer.